# What does MyClass(k=random.randint(1,7) == 1) mean?

Tags: python

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

x = MyClass(k = random.randint(1,7) == 1)
```

I know that `k = random.randint(1,7)` means that I'm passing the key "k" with value "random.randint(1,7)" as an argument, but what does "== 1" mean?

Comment: This will evaluate as a boolean, `True` or `False`, depending on the value of the left-hand side, i.e. `random.randint(1,7)`.

Comment: @dspencer so it will pass as an argument the key "k" with value "True" or "False"?

Comment: Yes, that's right - you can check the answer below from GoodDeeds.

Answer (score 3):

```
k = random.randint(1,7) == 1
```

can be read as

```
k = (random.randint(1,7) == 1)
```

That is, you generate a random integer in {1,2,3,4,5,6}, and compare it with 1. Then, you assign `True` to `k` if it is 1, else you assign `False`.